# Generate all combinations of words from nested list of letters

Tags: python, list, algorithm, traversal

The problem is to generate words in lexicographical order. So to generate `Allword` from `Letters`:

```
#we have a list containing lists which contains alphabets
#for eg.:
Letters=[['A','B','C'],['D','E','F'],['P','Q','R','S']]
#This is input and output is supposed to be like this
Allword=['ADP', 'ADQ', 'ADR', 'ADS', 'AEP', 'AEQ', 'AER', 'AES', 'AFP', 'AFQ', 'AFR', 'AFS', 'BDP', 'BDQ', 'BDR', 'BDS', 'BEP', 'BEQ', 'BER', 'BES', 'BFP', 'BFQ', 'BFR', 'BFS', 'CDP', 'CDQ', 'CDR', 'CDS', 'CEP', 'CEQ', 'CER', 'CES', 'CFP', 'CFQ', 'CFR', 'CFS']
```

I've used the iterative algorithm which is only useful when length of List Letters is 3

```
    for i in Letters[0]:
        for j in Letters[1]:
            for k in Letters[2]:
                    b=i+j+k
                    Allword.append(b)
```

I am trying to find an algorithm which can do same work but without limitation of length. How could I go about this?

Answer (score 3):

You need the cartesian product of the inner lists. You have [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) for that. Then just map the resulting tuples with [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2.5/lib/string-methods.html) to get a list of strings:

```
from itertools import product

list(map(''.join, product(*Letters)))
# ['ADP', 'ADQ', 'ADR', 'ADS', 'AEP', 'AEQ'...
```